# Using group policy migration table does not catch all occurrences

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, domain

I'm trying to use the `Group Policy Migration Table Editor` to make a conversion table for my import job...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And as you can see below, the results are somewhat positive but I can't seem to get it to account for all occurrences in the policy.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Arvo - Are you doing this across domains in the same forest, separate forests, a one-way trust, a two-way trust, or what? Can you clarify what you are expecting to see in the table "results" that you do not see otherwise with what you're doing here?

Comment: What I'm doing is trying to create a method to roll out single isolated one off domains.  I have the old domain that has nothing to do with the new domain.  They share the same policies though.  I guess I could have named them `domain1` and `domain2`, sorry I didn't mean to give the impression one was going away.  These domains are on a different subnet though...  So at no point can I have a single PC/Server that is on the same network as both domains.  I did try to achieve this once but realized that the server trying to use GPO manager has to be on the domain!  :/